# codeigniter models in controller is not loading

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

This is my controller:

```
class Orders extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

//get model and db entries
$this->load->model('order_model', 'orders', TRUE);

}}
```

When i open the corresponding url i get the content of the class php file.

```
class Order_model extends CI_Model { 
var $fullname = ''; var $email = ''; var $address = ''; 
var $phone = ''; var $notes = ''; var $facebook = ''; 
var $canvases = ''; var $admin_notes = ''; var $status = ''; 
var $id = ''; var $date = ''; 
var $price = ''; var $emailStatus_reciveOr...
```

I suppose it's something small and stupid but i can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: What does your `OrderModel` file look like?

Comment: How about your views?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string, try:

```
$this->load->model('order_model', 'orders');
```

The CodeIgniter class does document a third option for `load->model` but it is for telling the model to auto-connecting to your database.

Also, you are instantiating `order_model` as `orders` but your controller is also called `order`.  I would discourage this type of naming since it can create confusing to anyone (including yourself a few weeks from now) trying to read the code.

Comment: It *does* [document the third parameter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#conn). Your answer is wrong in this case.

Comment: Well spotted! I never read that page of CI docs before! Will fix! Thank you.  But why is the code being dumped out...

Comment: I don't know the answer to his question. I just know that the third parameter is not the problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm ashamed to admit it, but the error was very silly. At the model's file there was no `<?php` :) so the document was a simple text as php is concern.

Comment: I did ask to see your model file... oh well, at least you found the problem.